# Django is not showing media files in development but it is in production

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, heroku

The users profile pictures are loading fine on https://rossdjangoawesomeapp2.herokuapp.com/ but when I use http://localhost:8000/ none of them are loading. The problem only occurred when I uploaded my site to Heroku / AWS.

I tried un doing some of the changes to the code. I tried getting it back to a state where localhost was working fine. But then I ended up coming into more error messages. I found this [Django is not serving static and media files in development but it is serving in production](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57346918/django-is-not-serving-static-and-media-files-in-development-but-it-is-serving-in/57452128#57452128) but unfortuntely it didn't help me.

And my difficulty now is I don't really know where to begin looking for advice on how to fix the issue.

**Settings.py**

```
   """
    Django settings for django_project3 project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 2.2.6.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/
"""

import os
import django_heroku

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = os.environ.get('SECRET_KEY')
#SECRET_KEY = 'SECRET_KEY'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True
#DEBUG = (os.environ.get('DEBUG_VALUE')=='True')

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['rossdjangoawesomeapp.herokuapp.com', 'localhost', '127.0.0.1', 'localhost:8000'] 


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'blog.apps.BlogConfig',
    'users.apps.UsersConfig',
    'crispy_forms',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'allauth',
    'allauth.account',
    'allauth.socialaccount',
    'allauth.socialaccount.providers.facebook',
    'django_comments',
]

SITE_ID = 1

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    ]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'django_project3.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]


WSGI_APPLICATION = 'django_project3.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/static-files/
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
CRISPY_TEMPLATE_PACK = 'bootstrap4'
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'blog-home'
LOGIN_URL = 'login'

EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = os.environ.get('EMAIL_USER')
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD =  os.environ.get('EMAIL_PASS')
EMAIL_PORT = 587

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    #Needed to login by username in Django admin, regardless of 'allauth'
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',

    #allauth specifc authentication methods, such as login by e-mail
    'allauth.account.auth_backends.AuthenticationBackend',
    )

CRISPY_TEMPLATE_PACK = 'bootstrap4'

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = os.environ.get('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID')
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = os.environ.get('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY')
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = os.environ.get('AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME')


#AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = 'AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'
#AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = 'AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'
#AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = 'AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME'


AWS_S3_FILE_OVERWRITE = False
AWS_DEFAULT_ACL = None

DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage'

django_heroku.settings(locals())
```

**urls.py**

```
"""django_project URL Configuration
The `urlpatterns` list routes URLs to views. For more information please see:
    https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/http/urls/
Examples:
Function views
    1. Add an import:  from my_app import views
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('', views.home, name='home')
Class-based views
    1. Add an import:  from other_app.views import Home
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('', Home.as_view(), name='home')
Including another URLconf
    1. Import the include() function: from django.urls import include, path
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('blog/', include('blog.urls'))
"""
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from users import views as user_views

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('register/', user_views.register, name='register'),
    path('profile/', user_views.profile, name='profile'),
    path('login/', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name='users/login.html'), name='login'),
    path('logout/', auth_views.LogoutView.as_view(template_name='users/logout.html'), name='logout'),
    path('', include('blog.urls')),
    #path(r'^activate/(?P<uidb64>[0-9A-Za-z_\-]+)/(?P<token>[0-9A-Za-z]{1,13}-[0-9A-Za-z]{1,20})/$',
     #   user_views.activate, name='activate'),
    path('accounts/', include('allauth.urls')),
     path('password-reset/',
         auth_views.PasswordResetView.as_view(
             template_name='users/password_reset.html'
         ),
         name='password_reset'),
    path('password-reset/done/',
         auth_views.PasswordResetDoneView.as_view(
             template_name='users/password_reset_done.html'
         ),
         name='password_reset_done'),
    path('password-reset-confirm/<uidb64>/<token>/',
         auth_views.PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(
             template_name='users/password_reset_confirm.html'
         ),
         name='password_reset_confirm'),
    path('password-reset-complete/',
         auth_views.PasswordResetCompleteView.as_view(
             template_name='users/password_reset_complete.html'
         ),
         name='password_reset_complete')
    ]



if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Comment: how did you deploy your staticfiles?



 Did you use [`collectstatic`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#collectstatic) ?

Maybe - especially when using heroku - have a look into [whitenoise](http://whitenoise.evans.io/) too

Comment: Your [`DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#default-file-storage)-setting points to s3boto3. In development you may need different settings.

Comment: Before making the site live, we had not set DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE to equal anything.

Comment: Is it possible to assign different values to DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE based on whether your running your site locally or on the WWW?

Comment: I just tried doing #DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage'

but the problem has persisted